Polygon contract deployment takes long, really long
I am trying to deploy a smart contract with an NFT collection erc721, however I did the deployment couple of hours ago and still is not visible yet on polygon scan, I tried deploying several times, no errors however on harhat deployment comand, just printing the contract address that I then checked but again,empty page.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MintingThings is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string public baseURI;
    string private baseExtension;
    string public notRevealedTokenUri;
    //Override switches
    bool public paused = true;
    bool public revealed = true;
    bool public multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet = true;

    // check the max supply
    uint256 public maxSupply = 60; //adjust with image nmber

    event Minted(uint256 tokenId);

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initNotRevealedTokenUri,
        string memory _baseUri,
        string memory _baseExtension
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        notRevealedTokenUri = _initNotRevealedTokenUri;
        baseURI = _baseUri;
        baseExtension = _baseExtension;
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // internal
    function _notRevealedTokenUri()
        internal
        view
        virtual
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return notRevealedTokenUri;
    }

    // only owner.
    function mintTo(address to) external onlyOwner {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        uint256 tokenId = supply + 1;
        bool alreadyMinted = balanceOf(to) > 0;

        require(!paused, "Minting not allowed");

        require(supply < maxSupply, "No more NFTs remaining");

        if (!multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet)
            require(!alreadyMinted, "wallet already have the nft");

        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        emit Minted(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "tokenId provided doesn't exist");

        if (revealed == false) {
            return notRevealedTokenUri;
        }

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function toggleReveal() external onlyOwner {
        revealed = !revealed;
    }

    function setNotRevealedTokenURI(string memory _notRevealedTokenURI)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        notRevealedTokenUri = _notRevealedTokenURI;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) external onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function setPaused(bool _state) external onlyOwner {
        paused = _state;
    }

    function toggleAllowMultipleMintsPerWallet() external onlyOwner {
        multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet = !multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet;
    }

    function burnAll() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 currentSupply = totalSupply();
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= currentSupply; i++) {
            _burn(i);
        }
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function setMaxSupply(uint256 _maxSupply) public onlyOwner {
        maxSupply = _maxSupply;
    }
}

I deployed several times since there was nothign being deployed, probably a mistake, but was not sure what the problem was, I see now after loging on one of the deployments that Transaction hash: 0xd78aaec758d1af0c0066f4dbea833a6a0e0730c18efe484545e5dfe1b5079a6f Contract deployed in block: 63683589 Contract deployed to: 0x6fb7CFC8ca9AA8A2e0903e4A4BC014C16668854c
I an see on the transaction hash that is being indexed, and i am not sure why this is happening neither what it means exactly or if there is something I can do to solve this situation and get my contracts deployed, thanks a lot for your time and any guidance is more than welcome.

Have you added the Polygon network details in your hardhat.config.js file?

If yes, are you deploying your contract with the corresponding network flag like --network polygon?

Since at the end you managed to deploy, the cause for the long time was probably related to the RPC (maybe connection issues or it was under heavy load). Changing RPC usually solves this problem in my experience.
There are services like infura or alchemy that offer really good private RPC endpoints for free. I suggest making an account with all of them so you can change based on performance.
Also you mentioned about retrying the deployment multiple times. In this case make sure you are using the same nonce:
const nonce = await signer.getTransactionCount();
const contract = await factory.connect(signer).deploy(deployArgs, {nonce: nonce});

By default I believe ethers will use instead a nonce that increments even if the previous attempt isn't mined yet.

As already mentioned here, RPC endpoints play a significant role. I'd also add Chainstack nodes. There are different coupons and discounts for the Growth plan as well (stay tuned). But I think you can start with the Developer plan.
By the way, to check endpoint performance you can use https://compare.chainstack.com/.
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack.
